# How to add an image or an audio file upload support to RichTextUploadField through Django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ckeditor

I have a RichTextUploadField in my models which is added by ckeditor's library. I want to add a support to create simple html field related content which includes some `img` and `audio` tags. I have added a support to upload html content through admin just have no idea how to add support to create through API endpoint?

*models.py*

```
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Part(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    textfield = RichTextUploadingField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at', )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.explanation)
```

*settings.py* (*!some parts*)

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # third party installed apps
    'rest_framework',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    ...
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
...
### I am using html5audio package to upload audios
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                'html5audio',
            ]
        ),
    },
}
```

**Question**: How can I add support to create HTML content through an REST API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should implement two different endpoints which you can upload audio or image files. Note you should configure `upload_to` to the folder where `ckeditor` has an access. Following my custom implementation for what you are asking.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

import os
from uuid import uuid4


def get_custom_audio_upload_path(filename, instance):
    ext = str(filename).split('.')[-1]
    filename = f'{uuid4()}.{ext}'
    return os.path.join("uploads/custom_audio/", filename)


def get_custom_image_upload_path(filename, instance):
    ext = str(filename).split('.')[-1]
    filename = f'{uuid4()}.{ext}'
    return os.path.join("uploads/custom_image/", filename)


class CustomAudio(models.Model):
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to=get_custom_audio_upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.audio.name


class CustomImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_custom_image_upload_path)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

*serializers.py*

```
class CustomAudioSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomAudio
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomImageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomImage
        fields = '__all__'
```

*views.py*

```
...

class CustomAudioViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomAudio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomAudioSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser, ]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serialized = CustomAudioSerializer(data=data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list" or self.action == "retrieve":
            permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
        else:
            permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]


class CustomImageViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustomImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomImageSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serialized = CustomAudioSerializer(data=data)
        if serialized.is_valid():
            serialized.save()
            return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serialized.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == "list" or self.action == "retrieve":
            permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
        else:
            permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

*urls.py*

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from django.urls import path, include
from someapp.views import CustomImageViewSet, CustomAudioViewSet

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('customaudio', CustomAudioViewSet)
router.register('customimage', CustomImageViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)
]
```

Just a little explanation: when you upload a audio or image you should make a post request to the endpoint and you will get url for the result and just embed it into tag. It should retrieve it from your media folder.